# Ordering from most records with SQL join

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by

I have two MySQL tables below

> **tophits**
> id, account, time

AND

> **topsites**
> id, name, email, url

My topsites id is 1 (which is my tophits.account). I want to select the name and url FROM topsites and COUNT how many records there are in tophits for account=1 for the day.

So they will all echo out and which ever account has the most hits in will be at the top and etc etc

This is for codeigniter, I tried..

```
$this->db->select('topsites.name, topsites.url, topsites.id, COUNT(tophits.account) as hit_count',FALSE);
   $this->db->from('topsites');
   $this->db->where('active', '0');
   $this->db->join('tophits', 'tophits.account = topsites.id', 'left');
   $this->db->like('tophits.time', '2011-01-25'); 
   $this->db->order_by('hit_count');
   $this->db->limit(10);
```

But it only prints out one record, and there's more than one in there... Anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need GROUP BY the account (to show multiple accounts), and you also need to ORDER BY "desc" to see the most hits first

```
$this->db->select('topsites.name, topsites.url, topsites.id, COUNT(tophits.account) as hit_count',FALSE);
$this->db->from('topsites');
$this->db->where('active', '0');
$this->db->join('tophits', 'tophits.account = topsites.id', 'left');
$this->db->like('tophits.time', '2011-01-25'); 
$this->db->group_by('topsites.name, topsites.url, topsites.id');
$this->db->order_by('hit_count', 'desc');
$this->db->limit(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `group by` ,

you use an [aggregate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function `count`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `group by` on the tophits table:

```
$this->db->select('topsites.name, topsites.url, topsites.id, COUNT(tophits.account) as hit_count',FALSE);
   $this->db->from('topsites');
   $this->db->where('active', '0');
   $this->db->join('tophits', 'tophits.account = topsites.id', 'left');
   $this->db->group_by('tophits', 'id');
   $this->db->like('tophits.time', '2011-01-25'); 
   $this->db->order_by('hit_count');
   $this->db->limit(10);
```